# Change Selenium send_keys() encoding?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, unicode, web-scraping, web-crawler

Lately I've been building a webscraper, and everything was working nicely, but today I needed to scrap a page that uses the character "ñ" and I haven't been able to do it.

Say, I want to scrap `foobar.com`. I tried the following:

```
url = 'http://www.foobar.com/Search/'
browser.get(url) #navigate to the page

#Select searcher
search=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id='frase_busqueda']")[0]
search.click()

search.send_keys('Paulina Nuñez')
```

But this inputs `http://www.foobar.com/Search/?query=paulina%20nu%60ez`

Also tried:

```
search.send_keys(u'Paulina Nuñez')
```

And brings the same.

When I manually input 'Paulina Nuñez' in the search bar, the URL is `http://www.foobar.com/Search/?query=paulina%20nuñez`.

So, is there a way I can send an 'ñ' to my browser, without it being translated to whichever encoding?

Also, not sure if this is important, but if you explore the webpage's HTML code it has this line:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Would setting chrome's language solve this?

Comment: sendKeys("\u00F1") might work. See http://www.mythoughts.co.in/2012/12/sending-special-characters-and-key.html#.W45plX4nb3Q

Comment: Thanks both, I'll try both when I get home from work and report !

Comment: alternatively, you could see what the url is in the browser when you do it by hand, then jump straight to the search when you do browser.get("http://www.foobar.com/Search/?query=paulina%20nu%60ez" but with the right thing in place of the %60

Comment: @JeremyKahan before you try going directly to the url, check for javascript being executed on click or leaving the page to see if you want or need that code to be executed.